# Exception in thread “AWT-EventQueue-0” java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java

When I run a method that should download the item from the database, the following error will appear:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dke.ps.Tables.Item cannot be cast to com.dke.ps.Items.Item
    at com.dke.ps.Shop.Shop.loadItems(Shop.java:161)
    at com.dke.ps.Shop.Shop.init(Shop.java:122)
    at com.dke.ps.Shop.Shop.<init>(Shop.java:60)
```

This is my class com.dke.ps.Tables.Item -

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByItemid", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.itemid = :itemid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByName", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByDescription", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.description = :description")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByIcon", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.icon = :icon")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByType", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.type = :type")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findByPrice", query = "SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.price = :price")})
public class Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "itemid")
    private Integer itemid;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "icon")
    private String icon;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public Integer getItemid() {
        return itemid;
    }

    public void setItemid(Integer itemid) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (itemid != null ? itemid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item other = (Item) object;
        if ((this.itemid == null && other.itemid != null) || (this.itemid != null && !this.itemid.equals(other.itemid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dke.ps.Tables.Item[ itemid=" + itemid + " ]";
    }

}
```

And there is my com.dke.ps.Items.Item

```
**
 * General class for an item containing common information sutch as id, name,
 * description, path to an icon, price and type of an item.
 * @author valecvit
 * @author koresmi1
 */
public abstract class Item
{
    /**
     * Unique id of an item.
     */
    public int itemid;
    /**
     * Name of an item.
     */
    public String name;
    /**
     * Description of an item.
     */
    public String description;
    /**
     * Relative path to item image.
     */
    public String icon;
    /**
     * Type of an item.
     */
    public int type;
    /**
     * Price of an item.
     */
    public int price;

}
```

I really do not know where the problem is. Could anyone please explain to me the exception?

BTW

The is the getDbItems() method:

```
ArrayList<Item> dbItems = new ArrayList<>();

        EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();
        TypedQuery<Item> query = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i", Item.class);
        dbItems = new ArrayList<Item>(query.getResultList());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The expection show in the this:

```
listOfDbItems = server.getDbItems();
        listOfUsersItems = server.getPurchasedItems(user);
        dlmItems.clear();

        int numberOfItemsInDb = listOfDbItems.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInDb; i++)
        {
            dlmItems.addElement((listOfDbItems.get(i)).name);
        }
```

The first class was created through Persistence - Entity Classes from database and the second one I created. If I changed array list to ArrayList dbItems it throws me the error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList. Constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not aplicable

Thanks for help!

Comment: Which is this line  "at com.dke.ps.Shop.Shop.loadItems(Shop.java:161)"?

Comment: dlmItems.addElement((listOfDbItems.get(i)).name);

Comment: What is the type of "dlmItems"? and what is "(listOfDbItems.get(i)).name" return?

Comment: private DefaultListModel dlmItems = new DefaultListModel(); and     `private void loadItems()
    {
        listOfDbItems = server.getDbItems();
        listOfUsersItems = server.getPurchasedItems(user);
        dlmItems.clear();
        
        int numberOfItemsInDb = listOfDbItems.size();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInDb; i++)
        {
            dlmItems.addElement((listOfDbItems.get(i)).name);
        }
    }
` return nothing, its a void method

Comment: And listOfDbItems is ArrayList

Comment: ok so you didn't understand my question. Basically, the exception is saying your trying to cast or convert "com.dke.ps.Tables.Item" into "com.dke.ps.Items.Item". " dlmItems.addElement" is ArrayList of String? "(listOfDbItems.get(i)).name" is returning String? Casting is a runtime error whereas if you add a String into ArrayList of not String the compiler would have picked up. Perhaps trying to debug your code.

Comment: private DefaultListModel dlmItems = new DefaultListModel(); - this is a declaration of dlmItems.

Comment: Oh, I think i see the issue. "listOfDbItems.get(i)" returns com.dke.ps.Tables.Item whereas "dlmItems" expecting "com.dke.ps.Items.Item".

Comment: Yes, it is probably true :) How should it look like that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that "listOfDbItems.get(i)" returns com.dke.ps.Tables.Item whereas "dlmItems" expecting "com.dke.ps.Items.Item". You should change the DefaultListModel dlmItems = new DefaultListModel() to accept com.dke.ps.Items.Item or maybe convert Tables.Item objects into Items.Item object before adding to dlmItem.